# Is Oliver Purposely Referring to Bruce Wayne or Just Coincidence?

Tags: dc, arrowverse, arrow

Recently I decided to start watching the TV show Arrow, and recently made it to episode 5. While watching, he looks at his friend-turned-partner Digs, and says "You know us billionaire vigilantes--we do love our toys." Does this mean that he is aware of Bruce Wayne's activities as Batman, possibly inspired by them? Or is Queen just being a wiseass?

Comment: HA - I totally missed that comment. Great catch!

Comment: Just a comment for current and future answerers: OP said he just started to watch the show, and I've seen a LOT of spoilers on the answers. Please take this into consideration.

Answer (score 23):

It's not a coincidence, but it's not an in-universe reference. It's an "inside joke" of sorts.

Stephen Amell has gone on record multiple times as saying that he tries to get the writers to work as many DC references into his show as possible. There are limits to how much they can get away with, because the Batman properties are licensed elsewhere, but they still name-drop Superman or Batman (or others) when possible. Some times they make it into the show, sometimes they don't. Examples include:

- In an early interview, Amell says he tried to work a line into dialogue soon after his return, where he waves to someone off-screen and calls them "Bruce", implying that he and Bruce Wayne are friends. (It didn't make it in.)
- In the *Legends of Tomorrow* premiere episode, Rip Hunter talks about both "dark knights" and "men of steel"
- Felicity's code name is Overwatch because "Oracle" was taken. Oracle is the code name of Barbara Gordon, former Batgirl, who was crippled by Joker and is in a wheelchair.

The show's dialogue is written in such a way that Batman "probably does" exist in Gotham somewhere, but they can't *say* that. So whenever they can, the writers insert these kinds of remarks as a wink-and-nod to the fans, to let us know that the show does still exist within the broader DC universe.

Comment: There are non-dialogue references too. The first episode from The Flash includes a newspaper from the future where one of the front page stories is that Queen Consolidated and Wayne Enterprises are merging.

Comment: There are references to Green Lantern as well. A bomber jacket with the name Jordan, a couple references to Ferris Air (and a missing test pilot).

Comment: @Amadeus9 *Legends of Tomorrow* also has one episode where Rip has the names of Green Lantern villains as code words to activate commands on his spaceship.

Comment: Batman isn't licensed elsewhere, WB just has an embargo on Batman on TV. This used to be the case with Superman too, before he showed up on Supergirl.

Comment: Another indirect reference: in The Flash TV show, Barry Allen's phone in a parallel universe has buttons to call Bruce, Diana and Hal. So Batman most likely exists in a parallel universe.

Answer (score 15):

Is it an in-arrowverse reference?

## No

[**IGN Article 2014**](http://uk.ign.com/articles/2014/11/26/arrow-and-the-flash-cant-mention-gotham-or-metropolis)

> ...Arrow and Flash executive producer Andrew Kreisberg stressed that anything you see referencing Batman on the show is “a tease.”
>
> Explained Kreisberg, “Obviously, they have the Batman movies and there’s [the series] Gotham. DC are amazing partners and Geoff Johns, who’s the chief creative officer [of DC] and one of the developers of Flash and done episodes of Arrow, he’s been with us from the very beginning on both shows. There are things we can do and things we can’t.”
>
> Kreisberg noted, “I’m a huge fan of Nightwing,” and how exciting it was for him on Arrow “Getting to name check Blüdhaven and go there.” However, he said there are still restrictions in place even when it came to mentioning locations, adding, “There’s the cities that we can use and then there’s everything else. **I don’t think you’re going to be hearing ‘Gotham’ or ‘Metropolis’ [on Arrow or The Flash] anytime soon.”**

That said, since that article, there have been references to *Wayne Tech* in Flash (in a possible future).

[image]

Plus *Supergirl* (with Metropolis and Superman) is now part of the Arrowverse but **only** (AFAIK), as a separate part of the multiverse<sup>*</sup> and does not exist in the same universe as  Arrow/Flash/etc.

<sup>*These universes/multiverses are a tad confusing</sup>

So, the original stance is softening

---

Out-of-Arrowverse

Absolutely the script has a nod to Batman but the Arrowverse does not include explicit canon knowledge of the Bat-verse **yet**. Thus Oliver wouldn't know about Batman / Bruce Wayne **yet**.

As mentioned by @JasonBaker...

> In fairness, this doesn't mean there **isn't** a Batman, just that they can't explicitly mention him on the show.

Comment: So, pretty much just Oliver being a wiseass?

Comment: Not exactly, I mean yes but it's more of a wink to the audience than that.

Comment: In fairness, this doesn't mean there *isn't* a Batman, just that they can't explicitly mention him on the show. Notably, there *is* an "Oracle"

Comment: No, Overwatch is Felicity's codename. Oliver was going to use "Oracle", but (in his own words) "it was taken"

Comment: I think this is the best overall answer. And since Flash - even the future newspaper headline - is the same canon as Arrow, that means that the Wayne family does or will exist in the Arrow-verse.

Answer (score 8):

It's a fourth break wall, and a wink to the audience. There are two main reasons why there's no explicit Batman in the Arrowverse.

### 1. Copyright stuff

You know, the basic stuff. Batman is not part of the contract, so he can't be shown or mentioned, nor can be any of the related characters/places. Very similar to the MCU movies not being able to even use the word *mutant* because the X-men currently belongs to Fox.

You know, all the great stuff [Paulie_D's answer mentions](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/141712/69281) :)

### 2. Arrow is already Batman

I mean... in the arrowverse, Arrow has been given a lot of Batman's plot lines (being chosen by Ras'Al'Gul, marrying his daughter, forming his "family" of vigilantes, getting (one of) his love interests paralyzed by a villain... actually that Overwatch/Oracle reference was oddly specific (the only difference being that Overwatch/Felicity was the tech-comm-Cisco-person already *before* the accident)

So... even if some day they could get the rights... there's not much they could do with him, since they've pretty much turned Arrow into Batman. Yeah, he doesn't have the alfred, or the cool bat motives or the Joker, but... they've given Oliver all the "batman stuff" they could so there wouldn't be much room for a redundant character.

Actually I wonder if in that hypothetical case, they'd give Batman some Green Arrow plot lines...

Comment: Green Arrow is a pretty common substitute for Batman even besides the Arrowverse. *Smallville* did the exact same thing for the exact same reason. I'm pretty sure DC just decided one day they needed a spare Batman.

Comment: @KutuluMike Excelent point, I didn't know that. I admit that, even though I'm a bit of a comic nerd, "Green Arrow" is not my area of expertise. :)

Comment: No downvote, since the answer is technically accurate, but I disagree with the answer in general. There have been definite references to both Bludhaven AND WayneTech in the Arrow canon, so the possibility of there being a Batman in that universe is still a possibility. Given that Batman is generally considered an urban legend, there's no reason that Oliver would mention him by name, and no explicit reason we have to assume he doesn't exist.  Also, Oliver mentioned at one point that the codename "Oracle" was taken.

Comment: @Omegacron What you say is absolutely right and I didn't have the intention of my answer denying that fact. I'll edit later to clarify, thank you :)

Comment: It might be worth it to mention that Arrow also has Bludhaven as part of his being batman. http://arrow.wikia.com/wiki/Bl%C3%BCdhaven

Comment: Part of the problem is that a lot of Green Arrow's story has been as part of the Justice League, so he regularly fights the same villains (e.g. the League of Assassins) as other DC heros. His list of Green-Arrow-specific villains is pretty thin and they've used most of them (Merlyn, Deathstroke, China White, Count Vertigo, Cupid, Clock King, and even Drakon) already.

Comment: @KutuluMike, I'm now going to the "The Spare Batman" whenever anyone mentions the Green Arrow.  :D

Comment: (Do you have a link for the Smallville reference you made?  I must have missed that.)

Comment: @Wildcard I'll try to dig it the story, since it's really old by now, but *Smallville* early on wanted to bring in Batman but WB was holding him off for a possible Batman TV show (which took a decade but became *Gotham*), so they swapped in the "other" billionaire playboy vigilante instead.

Comment: _"I'm pretty sure DC just decided one day they needed a spare Batman."_ Haha spot on.

Comment: Honestly, I think the "billionaire playboy vigilante" category is really the only comparison between the two - no different than Tony Stark. It's just a comics trope in general. Personality-wise, the two characters are completely different, with a different theme, different outlook on crime & justice in general, and even a different M.O. altogether. Now, if we're referring only to the TV version from Arrow then I can see it. The comics versions, though,  don't seem interchangeable to me at all.

Comment: @Omegacron I don't know enough about the comic Green Arrow to either agree or disagree with you (though I feel you are right). But the TV Oliver Queen is definitely very Bruce Wayney. And of course, in my answer, I am refering to the TV one. I think that when KutuluMike said he is a "spare Batman", he means that Green Arrow is close enough and unknown enough (to the general public) to be easily adapted into Batman's role without generating a major outcry. You can't do that with... let's say...Flash. Or Aquaman. You could with Nightwing, ofc, but his copyright is usually tied to Batman's, so...

Comment: @xDaizu - gotcha. And, yeah, I'd have to agree with that. The TV version of Oliver is very serious and broody. The comics version has a much lighter tone - he deals with serious issues (like alcoholism, etc) yet constantly jokes around and taunts opponents. He's also commonly seen during daylight hours in bright green outfits, with his M.O. comprised of mostly trick arrows. The idea behind the character was literally Robin Hood as a modern crime fighter.